Add DB as federated data in unity catalog with entra id or non-user/password?
I see that databricks on azure can add SQL server and SQL data warehouse as federated data sources within the unity catalog. However it looks like it only supports username/password which seems like weak security. Is there another way to do it with a service principal and/or entra ID that would be more secure?

Yes, Microsoft Entra ID can be utilized for authentication when integrating SQL Server and SQL Data Warehouse as federated data sources in Databricks' Unity Catalog on Azure. By registering a Microsoft Entra ID application and creating a service principal with requisite permissions, access to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 or Blob Storage resources can be facilitated. This authentication method streamlines identity management by centralizing user identities and permissions across databases and Microsoft services.
